# xPath issue in NightwatchJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, nightwatch.js, custom-selectors

I am trying to test a command I created in NightwatchJS but I keep getting errors related to the selectors. The error is "expected 'visible' but got: 'not found'". This seems to be related to the second selector's xPath not being correct. 
[image]
The selector functions utilize the xPath and test the element using the Nightwatch method `.waitForElementVisible`. I created a common command (that is basically just a selector) outside of the command I am working in that successfully selects the element using a filename as an argument. The problem is the second selector (shoeboxDropdown), which takes the first selector(shoeboxSelectButton) and adds a /div. The shoeboxDropdown selector must be related to the shoeboxSelectButton. What I want to do is select the button and then click the dropdown menu for that button. If you look at the xPaths, you may see my delima.

shoeboxSelectButton:

```
  "//*[@id=\"sidebar-plugins\"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div[span/text()='" + filename + "']"
```

shoeboxDropdown:

```
//*[@id="sidebar-plugins"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div[2]
```

They both reside under the same list item `li`, but under separate `divs`. The text for the filename lives in `div[1]`, while the dropdown menu lives in `div[2]`. How can I use the first selector to get the second using the xPath?

```
shoeboxSelectButton = require "../Common/shoeboxSelectButton"

exports.command = (filename) ->
    mappx = @page.mappx()

    shoeboxDropdown = () ->
      shoeboxSelectButton(filename) + "/div"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK-After many trials I was able to figure it out. It seems that adding `//` allows the path to be derived from initial path. My solution looks somewhat like this and I was able to apply it to other slectors as well. First, I had to tweak the xPath for my shoeboxSelectButton selector to this (Note: this is in Coffeescript):

```
module.exports = (filename) ->
"//*[@id=\"sidebar-plugins\"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[.//span/text()='" + filename + "']"
```

Then, changed the code in my command to derive the selector for shoeboxDropdown (and shoeboxRemoveButton) to look like this:

```
shoeboxSelectButton = require "../Common/shoeboxSelectButton"

exports.command = (filename) ->
    mappx = @page.mappx()

shoeboxDropdown = () ->
    shoeboxSelectButton(filename) + "//em"

shoeboxRemoveButton = () ->
    shoeboxSelectButton(filename) + "//ul/li[3]/a"
```

Finally, I just had to make one call within the test file and wah-lah; it works! Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
browser.ShoeboxPanel.deleteShoebox "Typical"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the parent selector and then index to that second div. Something like this...

"//*[@id=\"sidebar-plugins\"]/div[1](https://www.simple-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/1269-Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf)/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1](https://www.simple-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/1269-Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf)/ul/li/div[span/text()='" + filename + "']/../div[2]"

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/xpath-css-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/ I personally use the [Rosetta stone pdf for xpath](https://www.simple-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/1269-Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf)  to figure out some of these types of cases.

Comment: Wow, that Rosetta Stone doc is great! Thanks. Unfortunately, adding `/../div[2]` didn't work.